# React - Any way to standardize import paths?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a website with a bunch of individual components, which I stored in a `components` folder in my folder architecture, and when I'm setting the routes, I constantly need to type out the whole file path. For example

```
let mathModules = "./components/MathModules/Programs/";

import MultiplesOf2 from mathModules+"Multiplicity101/MultiplesOf2";
```

For each module and future modules I constantly have to add `./components/MathModules/Programs/` where the only difference is the latter 2 substrings. The above code obviously doesn't work, but is there a way to achieve a similar effect without importing a "Routing" file that lives closer to the target path.

Comment: If you are using webpack checkout https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: are you using webpack as build tool ?

Comment: You can  use `index.js`.

Comment: I dont believe I am using a webpack tool